# Is there a way to get the exact location for the provided latitude, longitude in tomtom reverse geocoding api

Tags: reverse-geocoding, tomtom

I find difference in the requested latitude, longitude and the reverse geocoding response position(latitude, longitude). Although the location is almost accurate, I just wanted to check if we can get the exact location for the requested latitude and longitude.

I tried giving 17.429934,78.377021 as latitude, longitude respectively in request and I got 17.430004,78.377014 as position in the reverse geocoding api response.